# I have edit the code of youtube subscribe button at its working fine but I want to open on new tab after button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have got the code from this site https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

And the code is written below,

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCIDNtTEd4usBpbcKMm7wV2A" data-layout="default" data-count="default" ></div>
```

I want this code to be open on another page like when we used `target="_blank"`

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have all the information, what have yout tried, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: actually i am not getting any error i want to open the link on new page or you can say new tab. right now after clicking its opening in the same page & its leaving my web page to youtube page from preventing to leave the my web page I want this o be open in another tab

Comment: Can't you just wrap it in an <a target="_blank">  code here  <a/> ?

Comment: I have already tryed but no result from that